# Boostrap datepicker: How to set date and format

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker. I'm trying to set the date with format at the same time. How do I that?

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" name="StartDate">

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  setDate: DateValue
});
```

I was reading their docs but I can't find any example.

Comment: Show your input tag

Comment: @Muhaddis I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set using attribute `value` at input html. 
If you use php:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" name="StartDate" value="<?=date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

If you use `jquery` and `moment` plugin:

```
$('input[name=StartDate]').val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     startDate: '0d'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
```